# Difference between isInstance and isInstanceOf

Tags: scala

Is there a difference between `classOf[String].isInstance("42")` and `"42".isInstanceOf[String]` ?

If yes, can you explain ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For reference types (those that extend `AnyRef`), there is no difference in the end result. `isInstanceOf` is however much encouraged, because it's more idiomatic (and likely much more efficient).

For primitive value types, such as numbers and booleans, there is a difference:

```
scala> val x: Any = 5
x: Any = 5

scala> x.isInstanceOf[Int]
res0: Boolean = true

scala> classOf[Int].isInstance(x)
res1: Boolean = false
```

That is because primitive value types are boxed when upcasted to `Any` (or `AnyVal`). For the JVM, they appear as `java.lang.Integer`s, not as `Int`s anymore. The `isInstanceOf` knows about this and will do the right thing.

In general, there is no reason to use `classOf[T].isInstance(x)` if you know right then what `T` is. If you have a generic type, and you want to "pass around" a way to test whether a value is of that class (would pass the `isInstanceOf` test), you can use a `scala.reflect.ClassTag` instead. `ClassTag`s are a bit like `Class`es, except they know about Scala boxing and a few other things. (I can elaborate on `ClassTag`s if required, but you should find info about them elsewhere.)