# In Scala: "10.getClass.isInstance(10)" is false

Tags: scala

In Scala (v. 2.11) the following expression returns `false`:
`10.getClass.isInstance(10)`

According to my understanding of getClass, 10.getClass should be the class that 10 is an instance of, so the expression should return `true`.

What are the semantics that explain this result? Or is it a bug in Scala?

---

Here is a complete executable example, together with a few related expressions.

```
object Tmp {
  def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit = {
    println(10.getClass.isInstance(10)) // false

    println(10.getClass) // int
    println(10.isInstanceOf[Int]) // true
    println(classOf[Int].isInstance(10)) // false
    println(classOf[Integer].isInstance(10)) // true
    println(classOf[Int].isInstance(10.asInstanceOf[Int])) // false
    // println(classOf[Int].isInstance(new Int(10))) // does not compile: Int is an abstract class
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** 
As I understand from the answers, `x.getClass.isInstance(x)` will be true for x of a reference type, but not for x of a value type. So in generic code that relies on `x.getClass.isInstance(x)` (e.g., a type checking generic collection) one should type `x:T` with type parameter `T <: AnyRef`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168721/difference-between-isinstance-and-isinstanceof

Here it is explained. Use isInstanceOf, it's better for Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class.isInstance` takes an `Object`, so the argument is autoboxed and turned into a `java.lang.Integer` (there is no way for Scala to do anything else, `isInstance` is handled by JVM).

But `10.getClass` is handled by the Scala compiler, because JVM doesn't allow calling methods on primitives. It returns the primitive type `int` (as the second `println` shows), and an `Integer` is not an `int`.