# ClassTag.runtimeClass.isInstance does not work for AnyVal

Tags: scala, generics, scala-reflect

Working with scala ClassTags I have seen that classTag.runtimeClass.isInstance doesn't work properly when you use it with AnyVal objects. Here is a snippet where you can test it. Any ideas to make this work for AnyVal objects?

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
object Test {
  def extractField[U: ru.TypeTag](json: Map[String, Any], field: String)(implicit classTag: ClassTag[U]): Option[U] = {
    json.get(field) match {
      case Some(value) =>
        if(classTag.runtimeClass.isInstance(value))
          Some(value.asInstanceOf[U])
        else {
          None
        }
      case _ =>
        None
    }
  }
  val map: Map[String,Any] = Map("k1" -> 2.0, "k2" -> "v")
  extractField[Double](map,"k1") // RETURNS NONE
  extractField[String](map,"k2") // RETURNS Some("v")
}
```

BTW I am working with Scala 2.10

Comment: is this a scala bug?

Comment: Use isInstanceOf instead of isInstance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168721/difference-between-isinstance-and-isinstanceof

Comment: I can't use value.isInstanceOf[U] because it's a generic type, so I need to make use of classtag (value.isInstanceOf[U] is unchecked since is eliminated by erasure)

Comment: It seems to be the wrong type of Double?  `extractField[java.lang.Double](map,"k1")` returns `Some(2.0)`.  I have no idea what's going on - I thought scala.Double was basically interchangeable with java.lang.Double?  And just to test Samar's suggestion, using `if(classTag.runtimeClass.isInstanceOf[U])` allows funky results like this: `extractField[String](map,"k1") //Returned Some(2.0)` so that's not going to work.

Comment: classTag.runtimeClass.isInstanceOf[U] will always return true because the classtag is of U class, what I want to check is if value is of type U. In the other post a guy says: "If you have a generic type, and you want to "pass around" a way to test whether a value is of that class (would pass the isInstanceOf test), you can use a scala.reflect.ClassTag instead. ClassTags are a bit like Classes, except they know about Scala boxing and a few other things. (I can elaborate on ClassTags if required, but you should find info about them elsewhere.)" but it doesn't say how to make it

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825927/classtag-based-pattern-matching-fails-for-primitives but this works since 2.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is much simpler code showing the same issue:

```
val c = classTag[Double].runtimeClass
println(c) // double
println(c == classOf[Double]) // true
println(c.isInstance(0.0)) // false
```

`isInstance` takes an `Object`. `classOf[Double]` represents the "class" of JVM primitive `double` (and `classTag[Double].runtimeClass` is the same). Since an object can't be a primitive, `classOf[Double].isInstance(something)` will always be false.

`Map[String, Any]` doesn't actually contain `AnyVal`s, but only objects; when you write

```
val map: Map[String,Any] = Map("k1" -> 2.0, "k2" -> "v")
```

`2.0` is automatically boxed to `java.lang.Double`, so your code correctly tells you there is no `Double` under this key. But you can write a simple helper function (I thought it was in the standard library somewhere, but don't remember where):

```
private val boxedClasses = 
  Map[Class[_], Class[_]](classOf[Double] -> classOf[java.lang.Double], ...) // the rest of AnyVal classes
def boxed(c: Class[_]) = boxedClasses.getOrElse(c, c)
```

and then in `case Some(value)`:

```
if(boxed(classTag.runtimeClass).isInstance(value))
  Some(value.asInstanceOf[U])
```

Of course it can't tell the difference between `Double` and `java.lang.Double` in your map, because this difference doesn't exist (except at compile time).

Comment: is there a way to implement this check for AnyVal objects?

Comment: I've added a solution.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I am surprised that this tricky solution is the only way to do this...

Comment: The modern idiom is `def f[A: ClassTag](x: Option[Any]) = x match { case Some(_: A) => true case _ => false }`. This is broken only on 2.10.

Comment: @som-snytt Ah, right. Didn't remember it's applicable here.