# Can I check if a Scala object is of a given type is this type is a boxed primitive?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to define a function to check if an object is of a given type using reflection :

```
implicit class NoEraseInstanceOf(that: Any) {
  def noEraseInstanceOf[T: ClassTag]= {
    val targetClass = classTag[T]
    targetClass.runtimeClass.isInstance(that)
  }
}
```

It is working fine with most of types, but not with boxed primitive types like Int. Due to runtime type, an Int is seen as a java Integer for example :

```
scala> val i = 1
i: Int = 1

scala> i.noEraseInstanceOf[Int]
res1: Boolean = false

scala> i.noEraseInstanceOf[Integer]
res2: Boolean = true
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: See this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519373/classtag-runtimeclass-isinstance-does-not-work-for-anyval/39520376#comment66359070_39520376 in particular.

Comment: @alexey romanov Thanks!